# How to add custom Tags to EKS cluster nodegroup instances

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am launching EKS cluster using Terraform. In my nodegroup i am launching two instances but custom tagging is not happening to the instances where as its happening for eks cluster and nodegroup. Can anyone tell me how to add custom tagging like Name env application to the ec2 instances present in node group using terraform code?

Thanks & Regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group), currently there seems to be no direct way to pass the "Name" tag for naming the EC2 instances created by EKS Node Group.

This question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328382/how-can-i-name-eks-worker-nodes-provisioned-with-terraform), which you can refer to name your instances using the provided workaround.